# Scatter plot multiple columns from dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot, scatter

- I have a dataframe (97 columns x 30 rows). In this dataframe there
  are only 1 and 0.
- I want to plot it like a scatter plot, in which in the x axis the are
  the name of the columns and in the y axis the name of the indexes.

[my dataframe is like this][1]

- The output I want is similar to the photo, but the red dot must be
  there only if the value of the intersection between row and columns
  has a 1 value.
- If there is a 0 value nothing is plot in the intersection.[][2][the
  output scatter plot I want][3]

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFnQX.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsguk.jpg
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/keGC6.png

Comment: please dont post the image but post the code

Comment: what is your desired output

Comment: oh, there is no code yet, just two lines to read the dataframe xD
The output is the scatter plot with red dots

Comment: Is it possible to post the data of the data frame and make it accessible to us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way to do this is to use two nested loops for plotting the points conditionally on each dataframe cell:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

example = pd.DataFrame({'column 1': [0, 1, 0, 1], 
                        'column 2': [1, 0, 1, 0],
                        'column 3': [1, 1, 0, 0]})

for x, col in enumerate(example.columns):
    for y, ind in enumerate(example.index):
        if example.loc[ind, col]:
            plt.plot(x, y, 'o', color='red')
            
plt.xticks(range(len(example.columns)), labels=example.columns)
plt.yticks(range(len(example)), labels=example.index)
    
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]